# Mustard gas hydrolysis (at a very high rate)

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, hydrolysis, organosulfur-compounds

> Explain mustard gas hydrolysis at a very high rate:
>
> $\ce{Cl-CH2-CH2-S-CH2-CH2-Cl}$

I tried searching online but did not find this reaction anywhere. Can someone explain me the steps/mechanism of this reaction? Even some hints might help.

**My attempt:**

According to Wikipedia

> Solvolysis is a special type of nucleophilic substitution ($\mathrm{S_N1}$) or
>   elimination where the nucleophile is a solvent molecule. For certain
>   nucleophiles, there are specific terms for the type of solvolysis
>   reaction. For water, the term is hydrolysis; for alcohols, it is
>   alcoholysis; for ammonia, it is ammonolysis; for glycols, it is
>   glycolysis; for amines, it is aminolysis.

It clearly states that hydrolysis/solvolysis can only be $\mathrm{S_N1}$ or elimination. However I'm wondering how can $\mathrm{S_N1}$ occur on a primary carbon! Morever water doesnt seem to be a strong enough base for elimination. So what will be the preferred reaction mechanism?

Comment: The cation is somehow stabilized via S. Without S, it would be just ethyl chloride which hydrolyzes pretty slowly, as expected.

Comment: You mean SN1 occurs?What will be the end product?Can you link the mechanism?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Luckily I got the mechanism via Google Image Search.

[image: Mechanism of hydrolysis]

Internal attack by sulphur atom takes place during the reaction. This is called anchimeric assistance, neighbouring group effect or $\mathrm{S_N{NGP}}$. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neighbouring_group_participation) describes it well.

Comment: Yes, an $S_N1$ reaction takes place. As, @Ivan pointed out, if it weren't for the it would just be like ethyl chloride. The key to this whole process is the presence of lone pair of electrons on sulfur which it uses to stabilise the primary carbocation (by forming the triangular cation depicted).

Comment: @getafix I would rather say it an extended version of $\ce{S_N1}$ i.e. $\ce{SN_{NGP}}$.It's not strictly $\ce{S_N1}$.

Comment: Of course I agree. There is clear neighbouring group participation. Sorry, my comment did not make it explicit. However, I never knew $SN_{NGP}$ was a term..learn something new everyday

Comment: @getafix Never mind.We're all here to learn :-)!

Comment: Indeed. What I meant is that the rate determine step is unimolecular, i.e $S_N1$